# Como traduzir “gleich” e “selbe”?

Tags: significado, tradução

Em alemão, se duas pessoas estiverem usando um mesmo copo, diz-se «zwei Leute benutzen **dasselbe** Glas», se uma estiver usando uma cópia do copo do outro, diz-se «zwei Leute benutzen die **gleichen** Gläser». O problema é que, em português, tanto «duas pessoas usam um mesmo (exacto) copo» quanto «duas pessoas usam o mesmo copo» são ambíguas.

Eu não consigo pensar em um modo de traduzir *gleich* ou *selbe* tal que a frase não seja ambígua.

Então pergunto: como traduzir estas frases sem ambiguidade?

> Wir trinken Wasser aus demselben Glase (1 copo).
>
> Wir trinken Wasser aus den gleichen Gläsern (2 copos).

Comment: Oh @Lambie , cê fica dando os conhecimento nos comentário. Mais o povão quer ver seu prosa articulado numa hesposta, né?! :D

Comment: @bad_coder Sim, porque não tenho toda certeza. Nem sei falar alemão.

Comment: @Lambie mas pode responder uma thread em português ou inglês, o essencial é que gostamos de apreciar a boa escrita.

Answer (score 2):

É como a diferença entre as palavras [*igual*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/igual) (adj; nome.) e [*mesmo*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mesmo) (determinante; pronome.).

*Gleiche* também pode ter o significado de idêntico, ou como verbo igualar. Enquanto [*selbe*](https://pt.pons.com/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/portugu%C3%AAs-alem%C3%A3o/selbe?bidir=1) tem várias derivações mas na sua raiz leva sempre como significado *"o próprio"* (refere-se a um único e determinado objecto ou ser).

> «zwei Leute benutzen dasselbe Glas»

*"Duas pessoas usam o mesmo copo"*. (E.g. Bebem pelo mesmo copo - daí o singular.)

> Wir trinken Wasser aus den gleichen Gläsern

"*Nós bebemos água por copos iguais*". (Os copos eram indistinguíveis, do mesmo lote e fabricante sem nenhuma marca que os diferencie.)

Comment: @Schilive não te esqueças de aceitar a reposta senão é como das outras vezes em que apagaste a conta e as perguntas ficaram sem resposta aceite. Grande bagunça isso. Deves carregar para aceitar e se alguma resposta melhor surgir entretanto podes mudar e aceitar a outra.

Comment: bad_coder, eu pretendo aceitá-la, mas eu só gostaria de fazer uma crítica/pergunta antes. Ao meu ver, “duas pessoas usam o mesmo copo” é ambíguo, por mais que uma interpretação seja mais provável; com "duas pessoas vão à festa com o mesmo vestido", a interpretação de semelhança é mais provável, mas ainda assim é ambígua. Eu te fiz entender?

Comment: @Schilive duas (ou mais) pessoas usarem o mesmo copo [não é inédito](https://www.wilanow-palac.pl/the_custom_of_drinking_from_a_single_wine_glass.html) há inúmeros casos em que é prática cultural.

Comment: É um ótimo ponto, Schilive! Em "bebem pelo mesmo copo" é claro que é um único copo, selben; mas em "foram ao casamento com o mesmo vestido" é claro que são dois vestidos semelhantes, gleichen. Parece-me claro que a tradução não é simples direta.

Comment: Pois @Schilive mas isso não foi o que escreve-te na pergunta. De acordo com as regras do SE não podes invalidar uma resposta alterando a pergunta depois de estar respondida.

Comment: Não confundir os exemplos da pergunta com a pergunta em si. Os exemplos eram sobre beber pelo mesmo copo (único) ou por copos iguais (dois); mas a pergunta é sobre selbe (único) e gleiche (dois), e se existe maneira de dizer essas duas coisas especificamente diferentes em português (...ou se não dá).

Comment: bad_coder, desculpa pela demora (problemas técnicos). É o que o ANeves disse, na realidade. Mas, como eu havia dito, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @Schilive olá, isto foi culpa minha porque respondi à pressa. O que sucede (se não estou enganado desta vez) é que *gleichen* neste caso teria obrigatoriamente de ser usado com um objecto no singular, enquanto *selben* podia ser usado com objectos no plural. Eu não devia ter tentado responder sem mais pesquisa prévia (mas pensa nisso de por o copo no singular em *gleichen* e vais ver que resolve).

Comment: @bad_coder, como vários dizem aqui no Brasil, não esquenta.

Comment: @Schilive Noís tá aqui no norte. Se os cara não tem [esquentador](https://www.edp.pt/edp-store/categorias/aquecimento-de-agua/?filterType=4&order=4) vai esfriar.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta e direta:

Uma tradução sem ambiguidade não é difícil, uma vez que "gleich" significa *igual/semelhante* e "selbe" significa *o mesmo*.

- Wir trinken Wasser aus demselben Glase (1 copo) = **Nós bebemos água no/do mesmo copo.**
- Wir trinken Wasser aus den gleichen Gläsern (2 copos) - **Nós bebemos água em copos semelhantes/iguais.**   O fato de *copo* estar no plural já mostra que são dois copos.